# Getting the list of files in a subdirectory with complete path

Tags: python

I have a directory like this:

```
Main Directory
 - Subdirectory
    - subfile1
    - subfile2
 - file1
 - file2
```

when I do the list. I am seeing output like:

```
arr=os.listdir(.)
-Subdirectory1, file1, File2
```

How can I get the output as:

```
./file1
./file2
.subdirectory1/subfile1 
.subdirectory1/subfile2.
```

Basically I am looking for a file names inside the directories also. I am also looking for complete path.

Can you please let me know if there are any functions I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

This produces output like in your example. Current directory `.` is used as an example:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(path,file))
```

If you want absolute paths (starting with / on Linux or \ on Windows), start with an absolute dirname.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list for all your files within your `MainDirectory` with below code:

```
import sys,os

MainDirectory = "/tmp/"

filesList = list()
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(MainDirectory):
    for name in files:
        filesList.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Then the `filesList` list contains all of your files within that directory and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

With Python >= 3.4 you can do this with:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> for item in Path('c:/scratch').glob('**/*'):
...     str(item.absolute())
```

... and pathlib offers many more goodies too.